# iOS 10 - When/how to set the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate?

Tags: ios, notificationcenter

I'm updating my app to the new Local Notification framework. Everything works great, as long as I set the notification delegate in the application's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (notifs are scheduled and fired, and the delegate's `willPresent` and `didReceive` methods are called when they're supposed to).

However, I'm actually working on a Cordova plugin, so I don't want any plugin-specific code in the AppDelegate.

Via `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver`, I've registered to be notified whenever `NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidFinishLaunching` is posted, but the iOS 10 documentation states that the delegate must be set *before* the call to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` ends and they mean it quite literally: it stopped working.

Unfortunately, although there is an `application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` there is no `NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillFinishLaunching`, so there doesn't seem to be a way to execute code *before* the app finishes launching via the NotificationCenter...

Anyone else encounter this problem?